# MySql Count Rework and SUM Rework by Phase

Tags: mysql

i need some help regarding the following query in MYSQL.

I have following SQL Table:

[LINK](https://paiza.io/projects/e/TL0HbZfx_QtnyJycXBdjeQ)

I need to calculation the following:

**1. Query: Count of Rework by phase**

For example (based on orderid 749, see the Link)
The order was already three times in phase 01. The first occasion of phase 01 is to be calculated as "productive"(Right First Time). Any other repetition at the phase is "rework" (Process Deviation / Rework).
In case of this orderid (749) the counter for rework is 2.

**2. Query: Time (in Seconds) of Rework by phase (Process Deviation / Rework)**
In Case of the orderid 749, i calculated already in excel the time (in second) of rework by phase. I need just this also implemented via mysql.
For example:
[My Calcualtion in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi2t0.png)

In the phase "01.1" was three times the order.
The first occasion of the order (in seconds) was

360 second = "Right First Time"

The Sum of any other repetition at the phase is "rework"

Process Deviation / Rework = 12840 seconds

This is what i have to implemented via MYSQL Query.
Please help me.

Thank you für your time and for your support.

BR,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

The problem is already solved:

```
SELECT SH.newphase , SUM(CASE WHEN SH.id = T.minid THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, SH.created, IFNULL(SH5.created, NOW())) ELSE 0 END) AS jo , SUM(CASE WHEN SH.id <> T.minid THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, SH.created, IFNULL(SH5.created, NOW())) ELSE 0 END) AS nemjo FROM Sol_Afo_History SH LEFT JOIN (SELECT SH2.orderid, SH2.newphase, MIN(SH2.id) AS minid FROM Sol_Afo_History SH2 GROUP BY SH2.orderid, SH2.newphase) T ON T.orderid = SH.orderid AND T.newphase = SH.newphase LEFT JOIN (SELECT SH3.id, (SELECT MAX(SH4.id) FROM Sol_Afo_History SH4 WHERE SH3.orderid = SH4.orderid AND SH4.id < SH3.id) AS elozid FROM Sol_Afo_History SH3) SHKOV ON SHKOV.elozid = SH.id LEFT JOIN Sol_Afo_History SH5 ON SHKOV.id = SH5.id WHERE SH.orderid='749' GROUP BY SH.newphase
```